# Calculate seasonality of Timeseries with frequency=1

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am really new into Timeseries and I am still trying to learn them. I have dataset that looks like this below as an example I use:

```
Έτος Έσοδα
2011 37.44
2012 44.14
2013 46.25
2014 43.99
2015 51.84
2016 49.10
2017 58.56
2018 58.02
2019 70.28
```

What I am trying to find are the trend and seasonality, mainly the seasonality. I know that there is the *decompose()* function, however there is no use in that case, because it has frequency = 1. Is there any other way I can calculate the seasonality of the give data?

P.S. I am using R.

Comment: Just plot it.  There is a trough at 2014, 2016 and 2018 so it looks like there is a 2 year cycle.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Hello! Shouldn't I create somehow a line, that would represent the seasonality of this timeseries?